# Div com float não se ajusta a grade

Tags: html, css, float

Estou desenvolvendo um site e ele deve listar algumas especificações de um sistema.
São várias listas de alturas variadas.
Problema: Utilizo o float: left em todas as listas. Eu esperava que as listas se ajustassem automaticamente, tando na direita quanto a esquerda. Mas como o esperado, isso não aconteceu.
Seguem fotos para melhor entendimento:

[image: A lista da direita é ajustada automaticamente, mas a da esquerda segue o limite da outra.]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow em português! Visite o [tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona! Por favor, coloque o código referente ao problema relacionado na pergunta também para que seja possível identificar o problema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre forneça o código necessário para a resolução do problema. A solução é utilizar a propriedade `display: inline-block`, assim todas as listas se alinhariam uma ao lado da outra. Junto a isso, você também pode utilizar a propriedade `vertical-align` para controlar como o posicionamento das listas irão se comportar. Dentre diversos valores, o que mais deve se adequar à sua necessidade é o `middle`, que posiciona centralmente um elemento em relação ao eixo Y.

Utilizando o código que você forneceu em sua resposta, fiz um exemplo no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr719e5f/1/. Em fullscreen para ver melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/hr719e5f/embedded/result/

Comment: Não conhecia essa propriedade vertical-align, vou dar uma olhada nela. Obrigado pela atenção. Acabei fazendo de outra maneira, para evitar estes espaços entre as listas. Criei uma div para o conteudo a esquerda e uma para a direita, e float left e right. Ficou bom porém o código ficou mais sujo do que eu esperava.